# Detect when a finger moves away from an object on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I have a HTML5 app which runs on mobile browsers. In it, if a user presses a button, moves the finger away from the div and then lifts the finger up, then the touchend event doesn't fire, and the button remains "pressed".

Is there any way to detect when this is happening? I'm trying to avoid a complex solution like listening for touchend events on the entire screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior. The same thing should happen with a mouse.

That said, the `touchend` event will not fire on the element on which it started, but should fire on the `body` element. If you listen for it there, you can check and see if there is any buttons that are active, and if so you can set them to inactive (`blur()` if you use CSS).